# Want to test services by printing it in template

Tags: python, flask, service

I have an api, but i want to test my flask service, by printing it flask templates. but this code prints me error. Does somebody know how to fix it?
ERROR: "TypeError: test_service() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'"

```
# @injector.inject
@staticmethod
@app.route('/test', methods=['GET'])
def test_service(self):
    p = self.BakkaraRoomService()
    p.get_rooms()
    return render_template('bakkara_room/room_list.html', p=p)
```

Comment: Functions outside a class shouldn't have `self` as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've programmed a function, but you want a class/object. A class won't work, because flask uses functions in this context. You'll need to simply define "BakkaraRoomService()" as it's own class/object somewhere in your code (likely just above your function), from there, you can call it like you are, but without "self", as you can't use self within a function like that.

```
class BakkaraRoomService():
    def __init__(self, param1, param2):
        self.param1 = param1
        self.param2 = param2
        # etc...

    def get_rooms(self):
        self.param1_plus_5 = self.param1 + 5
        
    

# @injector.inject
@staticmethod
@app.route('/test', methods=['GET'])
def test_service(self):
    args = request.args
    param1 = args.get('param1')
    param2 = args.get('param2')
    p = BakkaraRoomService(param1, param2)
    p.get_rooms()
    return render_template('bakkara_room/room_list.html', p=p)
```

Comment: BakkaraService with Inject annotation and test_service() requires paratemeters

Comment: I will update my response to trivially include params